How do I add a link to pandas HTML header
I have a python script which imports a CSV file and then manipulates the data and then outputs it as html using df.to_html.  I'd like to be able to click on the column heading to call a function to sort the rows.  I'm currently doing the sorting via a button press.  I've added links to data rows in the table, but cannot figure out how to have df.to_html add the onClick for the header.
An example html is:
<table>
<th id="text" onClick="mySortFunction()">Column Heading</th>
  <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
</table>


You have to edit the file to add the code for the function, right?  This is just one more edit.

Pandas itself is not made to add these features. However, you can use the table_id attribute on the to_html() method though to make it easy to identify the table on your HTML page. Then you could use a library like datatables, to add sorting and other functionality for you.
So something like:
python code:
html_str = df.to_html(None, table_id="myPandasTableId")

The html file:
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.4/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- pandas table goes here -->
  <script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.1.4/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   let myDataTable =  new DataTable('#myPandasTableId');
</script>

</body>
</html>


Thanks.  That did the job, although I had to add '' before dataTables javascript line.
